# Manuel's trick and oracle separation

Tags: oracles, separation

Impagliazzo gave a [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kej36yXKKeY) last week at Simons Institute on oracle separation. At minute 5:34 he asks whether a one-way permutation can be constructed given oracle access to a random function oracle. Then he explains why it is tricky using "history and pre-image" paradigm.

This paradigm wasn't clear to me although it seems a cornerstone. Could someone volunteer to explain it?